# Recursing into objects without infinite loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm traversing objects in javascript for the purpose of learning.  Right now that amounts to spitting out each property in the first object the function is given and recursing into any child objects it finds (including functions).

Using the window object as an example, the function gets stuck in an infinite loop as window.top points to window.  How should I best track which objects I've already traversed in order to avoid recursing into them?

Comment: In JS, you can add properties to any object, even native ones. So you could say `currentObj.didProcess = true`. `currentObj` may be `window`, an `HTMLElement` instance or a function too.

Comment: There's a tiny possibility of a conflict though, because some other code might be creating properties with the same name. You'll also have to make sure that the properties you create are deleted after the code executes, which includes handling possible errors. I'd consider modifying objects like that a bad practice in general, since it potentially affects other code.

Comment: "traversing the DOM" != "recursively traversing circular objects"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to store the objects you're currently looking into. This should help with detecting circular references:

```
var stack = [];
function traverse(object) {
  if (stack.indexOf(object) !== -1) {
    return; // if the condition above is true, we have a circular reference
  }
  stack.push(object);
  // here go through object properties, recursively calling traverse()
  stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and see if we're missed something.  This was one of my thoughts, but I think I dismissed it because I couldn't see how to compare objects.  Will accept this if it works!